# ASP.Net caching manager

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Cache Helper Class.

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public static class CacheHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Insert value into the cache using
    /// appropriate name/value pairs
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of cached item</typeparam>
    /// <param name="o">Item to be cached</param>
    /// <param name="key">Name of item</param>
    public static void Add<T>(T o, string key) 
    {
        // NOTE: Apply expiration parameters as you see fit.
        // I typically pull from configuration file.

        // In this example, I want an absolute
        // timeout so changes will always be reflected
        // at that time. Hence, the NoSlidingExpiration.
        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(
            key,
            o,
            null,
            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1440),
            System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove item from cache
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">Name of cached item</param>
    public static void Clear(string key)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove(key);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check for item in cache
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">Name of cached item</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool Exists(string key)
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Cache[key] != null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieve cached item
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of cached item</typeparam>
    /// <param name="key">Name of cached item</param>
    /// <param name="value">Cached value. Default(T) if 
    /// item doesn't exist.</param>
    /// <returns>Cached item as type</returns>
    public static bool Get<T>(string key, out T value) 
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Exists(key))
            {
                value = default(T);
                return false;
            }

            value =  (T) HttpContext.Current.Cache[key];
        }
        catch
        {
            value = default(T);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

and usage:

```
string key = "EmployeeList";
List<Employee> employees;

if (!CacheHelper.Get(key, out employees))
{
    employees = DataAccess.GetEmployeeList();
    CacheHelper.Add(employees, key);
    Message.Text =
        "Employees not found but retrieved and added to cache for next lookup.";
}
else
{
    Message.Text = "Employees pulled from cache.";
}
```

Do you see any improvement / issue?

Comment: You can view updated version of code here: http://www.coderemarks.com/review/LIgmRrlPmwJ2PEuk

Answer (score 12):

> ```
> /// <summary>
> /// Insert value into the cache using
> /// appropriate name/value pairs
> /// </summary>
> /// <typeparam name="T">Type of cached item</typeparam>
> /// <param name="o">Item to be cached</param>
> /// <param name="key">Name of item</param>
> public static void Add<T>(T o, string key)
> ```

I think this signature would be more useful like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Insert value into the cache using
/// appropriate name/value pairs.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type of cached item (inferred from usage).</typeparam>
/// <param name="key">A string used to uniquely identify the added value.</param>
/// <param name="value">Item/value to be cached.</param>
public static void Add<T>(string key, T value)
```

---

This is misleading:

> ```
> /// <summary>
> /// Remove item from cache
> /// </summary>
> /// <param name="key">Name of cached item</param>
> public static void Clear(string key)
> {
>     HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove(key);
> }
> ```

`Clear` is usually a parameterless method that *clears* a container's contents. This method should be named `Remove`.

---

> ```
> /// <summary>
> /// Check for item in cache
> /// </summary>
> /// <param name="key">Name of cached item</param>
> /// <returns></returns>
> public static bool Exists(string key)
> {
>     return HttpContext.Current.Cache[key] != null;
> }
> ```

*"Check for item in cache"* doesn't really say what's going on. I realize it's trivially inferred from the method's name, but *"Checks for existence of specified key in cache."* would be totally unambiguous.

---

> ```
> public static bool Get<T>(string key, out T value)
> ```

I don't like the implementation of that method very much, there are too many exit points, some being redundant. Consider something like this:

```
public static bool TryGet<T>(string key, out T value) 
{
    bool result;

    try
    {
        if (Exists(key))
        {
            value =  (T)HttpContext.Current.Cache[key];
            result = true;
        }
    }
    catch(InvalidCastException)
    {
        value = default(T);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for very useful style guidelines.
But I don`t understand about using `HttpContext.Current.Cache.Items`. `HttpContext.Current.Cache` does not contain a definition for `Items`. If you mean `HttpContext.Current.Items` this is not the same. `Items` is per request, so it`s only available for that given user for that given HTTP request. `Cache` is stored in memory for a persistent period of time, and it not dependent on the specific user. So cache can be shared across multiple users across multiple requests, but `Items` is per user per request.

Comment: I meant the *indexer* - `Cache[n]` should be the same as `Cache.Items[n]`. I'll read up on that, I don't use an `HttpContext` very often.

Comment: Yes, I know it, but I can't use `HttpContext.Current.Cache.Contains(key)`, because in `HttpContext.Current.Cache` has no definition of `Contains()` or something like this.

Comment: Looks like I was looking at the wrong MSDN docs.. the indexer uses the `Item` property and indeed there's no `Items` property. Sorry for the mix-up, edited my answer.

Answer (score 9):

```
try
{
    if (!Exists(key))
    {
        value = default(T);
        return false;
    }

    value =  (T) HttpContext.Current.Cache[key];
} catch {
    value = default(T);
    return false;
}

return true;
```

This contains some duplicate logic. We can rewrite it like this:

```
if (Exists(key))
{
    value = (T) HttpContext.Current.Cache[key];
    return true;
}

value = default(T);
return false;
```

Advantages:

- No negative condition check
- No duplication of the `default(T)`
- No expensive try-catch (all) block

Comment: +1 I like this simple & neat implementation. However `try/catch` is only "expensive" if the stack gets unwinded, i.e. if an actual exception is thrown... and there's a possible `InvalidCastException` if the cached object can't be cast to `T` - granted it's a *misuse*, but still a possible execution path. The class can't assume its client knows what it's doing ;)

Comment: Good point about the `InvalidCastException`. If you want to explicitly catch it then you can add it but it would give the impression that a key is not present and thus would hide the problem in its implementation. Since it is impossible in the first place to use multiple equal keys, I think throwing the exception is more appropriate (it also helps with debugging)

Comment: not necessarily: the method infers the type of `T` from the `value` parameter, which puts the entire responsibility of knowing the type of a cached item, on the caller, regardless of whether or not the specified key exists, hence my distrust for the [assumed-to-be-]safe cast.

Comment: The alternative by catching the exception would be to return `null` so the user would have to explicitly call `Exists` before `Get` and make some weird flow to account for the possibility that the key might exist but he's trying to retrieve it with the different type (which doesn't show up any different from not having the key in the first place). Since there shouldn't be any surprise as to what type a key is, I don't think it adds any value to hide the exception (but it will show up as an immediate problem if you used the wrong type).

Comment: Damn, blinded by the trees again - you're right, it's best to just let the `InvalidCastException` bubble up, it's the most meaningful result a caller can get (vs a `default(T)` value and a `false` result for a `key` that *does* exist).

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest one more solution how to make usage a bit easier. You can add this method into `CacheHelper`

```
public static T GetOrAdd<T>(string key, Func<T> getter)
{
    T value;
    if (!TryGet<T>(key, out value))
    {
        value = getter();
        Add(value, key);
    }

    return value;
}
```

In that case usage can be a bit simplier, but in that case you won't know is item existed in cache or not

```
string key = "EmployeeList";
List<Employee> employees = CacheHelper.GetOrAdd(key, () =>  DataAccess.GetEmployeeList());
// or even like this if method matches signature
List<Employee> employees = CacheHelper.GetOrAdd(key, DataAccess.GetEmployeeList);
```

If item doesn't exist, then it will call lambda,  and will add it to the cache

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think we can write your function a bit simpler. Please, view my version of it. http://www.coderemarks.com/review/LIgmRrlPmwJ2PEuk

Comment: Yeah, with `TryGet<T>` it looks better!